# Proof of the remarkable formula for the n-th non-square?

Tags: sequences-and-series, square-numbers, oeis

The [OEIS's A000037](https://oeis.org/A000037) entry makes the remarkable claim that every non-square number is given by the sequence $$a(n) = n + \Big\lfloor \frac 12 + \sqrt n\Big\rfloor$$ After looking through the entry, I couldn't find anything that looked like a proof or a link to one. Is there a simple proof of this?

Comment: That OEIS article has a link to https://www.jstor.org/stable/3618253?seq=1 which seems to contain a proof of that statement.

Comment: $a(n+1)-a(n)=1$ unless there's an integer between $\frac12+\sqrt n$ and $\frac12+\sqrt{n+1}$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Very smart! Add some spit and polish and you'll have an answer right there.